# How to find Docs for Jest, Enzyme, Create-React-App, Shallow()?

Tags: jasmine, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

Im using Create React App and have set up my test files like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
```

Then I set up wrapper  using shallow() like this:

```
let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const defaultProps = {
      color: 'orange',
      value: 17,
      title: 'live services',
      link: 'htttp://google.com'
    };

    wrapper = shallow(<Callout {...defaultProps} />);
  });
```

Im using assertions that I have been using for a while such as

```
expect(wrapper.find('h5').html()).toContain('some title');
expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<Foo />)).toBe(true);
```

These assertions work but i want to find more.

I have no idea where to find the docs for the assertions that are available to me.
The assertions I have working so far look a bit like Jasmine assertions in that they are using camel case but the methods are still named differently.
https://jasmine.github.io/

I thought I was using jest and enzyme but the assertions are completely different to those in the Enzyme docs
https://airbnb.io/enzyme/
For example

```
expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.lengthOf(3);
```

Does not work. These methods of find() are not available to my current set up.

In the Jest Docs I can only find assertions for testing javaScript functions and can't find any methods for traversing and testing Virtual DOM or shadow DOM elements like the ones I have been using( see above)

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object

How do I see what assertions are available to shallow() and shallow.find() with my current setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Jest assertion methods here [Jest assertion methods](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect)

You could also look at this library package https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-enzyme

Comment: I can't find the assertions I have been using to test the virtual DOM in the Jest DOCs - the library you mentioned looks interesting - I might try it out but how do I find a list of the currently available assertions?